# Why is this very basic unit test failing (ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.0.9)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

test/unit/user_test.rb holds:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

And executing:

```
perrys-MacBook-Pro:iway perry_mac$ ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb
```

Yields the following:

```
Loaded suite test/unit/user_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.006410 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_the_truth(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: user_sessions: DELETE FROM "user_sessions" WHERE 1=1
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `rescue in log'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:199:in `log'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:135:in `execute'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:288:in `update_sql'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:139:in `update_sql'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:293:in `delete_sql'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:145:in `delete_sql'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:54:in `delete'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:16:in `delete'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:569:in `delete_existing_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:531:in `block (4 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:531:in `each'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:531:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:530:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:109:in `disable_referential_integrity'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:521:in `block in create_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:55:in `silence'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:520:in `create_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:979:in `load_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:944:in `setup_fixtures'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
    /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:34:in `run'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

The error statement comments on an SQL DELETE query, which seems bizarre.  And why is it even referencing user_sessions here?  This test used to pass.  After some db migrations (adding columns to existing tables) it does not.  Can someone help me bridge my understanding gap here? Is there some mysterious entity that I have to reload.  I tried each of:

```
rake db:test:clone  
rake db:test:clone_structure    
rake db:test:load   
rake db:test:prepare    
rake db:test:purge
```

... but still see the same output.  I can drop my current git branch and start over, but I'd really like to understand what tripped me up first.  Please indicate if there is a log or other source of info I should be looking at to untangle the problem.

ADDENDUM (schema.rb):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110901142600) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "last_request_at"
    t.datetime "current_login_at"
    t.datetime "last_login_at"
    t.string   "current_login_ip"
    t.string   "last_login_ip"
  end

end
```

Comment: What is your schema.rb file? Can you post it?

Comment: Have you got your test database configured in your `database.yml` file?

Comment: Will post schema now.  I have not added or removed anything to/from the default database YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key is in the 10th line of the stack trace:

```
/Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:569:in `delete_existing_fixtures'
```

Notice `fixtures.rb` and `delete_existing_fixtures`. Rails cleans all the fixtures out of the database before running your test suite. Do you have a `user_sessions.yml` file in `test/fixtures`?

Comment: yes.  I just renamed it to: user_sessions.yml.sav and the test now passes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with David; it looks like you're using authlogic (or similar) and <strike>don't have a complete user_sessions setup</strike> generated the default model fixture--how did you create your UserSession model?

Comment: rails g model user_session  as detailed in the online offering here: http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/

Comment: And to further detail where I went wrong here....  I gather I created a model with no corresponding table.  The creation of the model user_session also created a user_session.yml under test/fixtures (and in other spots too).  When invoking 'rake test' fixture data is deleted and re-created.  Since no user_session table exists, the pre-testing delete/create threw an error.

Comment: Did I side-step "best practice" by not creating a user_sessions table?  It seems the controller and model are enough.  To facilitate testing, should I create a rudimentary user_session table too? Many thanks again - Perry

Comment: No table is necessary; authlogic sessions _look_ like ActiveRecord models, but aren't really. Models can be generated without creating a corresponding fixture file by using --skip-fixture or --fixture=false.

Comment: No problem--that caught me up as well; I had assumed using the authlogic:session generator wouldn't create a fixture, but it does, just like the default model generator.